# How to filter entries from a list based on a criteria and get the index in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list say list=[1,4,6,3,2,1,8] and I want to filter this list based on the condition that entry>3 and return the corresponding index.

So the output should be : [1,2,6] which corresponds to the values 4,6 and 8.

how to do this efficiently in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```py
l = [1,4,6,3,2,1,8] # you should not overwrite the list builtin
res = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x > 3]
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P0fBViHaUMdEx0zHWMdIx1DHIparKLUYJJqpkJZfpJCpo1ChkJmnkJpXmptalFiSqpGjqZCZBhS0UzCO5Sooyswr0QDq0Pz/HwA)